# Ansible for loop with mutiple with sequence

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

In Python I use below code: to print 1 to 5 and 11 to 15

```
for i in range(1, 6) + range(11, 16):
     print i
```

Is there similar method in ansible Playbook to achieve the same.

I see with_sequence is available like below I can use it

```
with_sequence: start=1 end=5
```

But I cannot able to achieve this in one loop, I may end up with using two loops one for start=1 end=5 and second one is for start=11 end=15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be an option:

```
tasks:
  - debug: msg="{{ '%02d' | format(item) }}"
    loop: "{{ range(1, 6)|list + range(11, 16)|list }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

In ansible loop option given and with_sequence is replaced by loop and the range function accordingly to ansible doc
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-sequence

```
- name: a play that runs entirely on the ansible host
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: range task
    debug: 
       msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: 
      - "{{range(1, 6)|list + range(11, 16)|list }}"
```

**output**:

```
PLAY [a play that runs entirely on the ansible host] *************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [range task] ************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]) => {
    "msg": [
        1, 
        2, 
        3, 
        4, 
        5, 
        11, 
        12, 
        13, 
        14, 
        15
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

**ansible version:**
ansible 2.7.1